# How to cancel contentresolver applyBatch?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I've built an application that requires to export 2000 contacts to native Android Contacts. I use contentresolver.applyBatch to make this happen, but if the user logs out I want to delete all of the apps exported contacts. It can occur that the contentresolver is not fully finished with saving the contacts.

**My question:**

How can I cancel the following opperation?:

```
resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I've tried to cancel the sync of the contentresolver like this:

```
ContentResolver.cancelSync(null, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY);
```

This doesn't work and I'm also not sure about the null value. It says it needs an account to stop syncing it for. But I'm not starting the sync on a specific account so why would it be needed?

**What I need?**

Something like resolver.stopBatch (a way to stop applying the batch).

Thank you for all your effort reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the use case, you're syncing in **new** `RawContacts` into the device, when a user logs into your app.

If that's the case, you should create a `SyncProvider`, and have it sync in RawContacts on an account that is tied to your app and package name.
That way, when a user uninstalls your app, the account is automatically removed along with the data you've synced into the device, and when a user logs out of her account, you simply remove the contacts account programatically, which will also remove all data synced to the device.

Read these tutorials on how to create a contacts account, a `SyncProvider` and use it to sync contacts on your account:

- http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/
- http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/
- https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Comment: It took me some time to read all those links, but how does the creating of RawContacts work in the Sync Adapter? Still with a ContentResolver?

Comment: yes, putting things in the DB is the same, just make sure the account_type and account_name values of your new RawContacts belong to your own created account

Comment: I am definetely going to look into it. It still contradicts my feeling because I think it's strange to create an account for this. But I think I definetely need a SyncService and as I read in the tutorials, you need an account for that. Thanks for your answer I'll let you know if and when I succeeded :).